# Is there a way to add multiple children to a canvas in a cycle?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

First of all, sorry for the question what may seem quite easy for some, but I just started learning WPF this Semester.

I am writing a WPF project as a Semester "objective". I am supposed to use JSON data to place my object (a space ship) on the screen. If I only put one of the ships on the screen, I can easily add it this way:

```
...
ship.Name = users[y].name;            
this.RegisterName(ship.Name, ship);
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("C:/Users/Szabi/Desktop/spaceship.png", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi3.EndInit();
ship.Source = bi3;
ship.Width = 100;
ship.Height = 150;
distance = Convert.ToDouble(shiplist[i].Distance);
velocity = Convert.ToDouble(shiplist[i].Velocity);
_angle = Convert.ToDouble(shiplist[i].Angle);
while (_angle[i] > 6.28)
  {
    _angle[i] = _angle[i] - (2 * Math.PI);
  }
left = (Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(shiplist[i].Angle))) * distance[i];
top = (Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(shiplist[i].Angle))) * distance[i];
Canvas.SetLeft(ship, (left + (sun.Width)));
Canvas.SetTop(ship, (top + (sun.Height)));
canvas.Children.Add(ship);    
ship.ToolTip = ship.Name;
...
```

I can then move it by changing the Canvas.SetLeft and SetTop in a new method that I call every second or so.

However if I try to put this into a cycle, and create as many of these ships as many ID's are on the server, it obviously doesnt work, because the canvas can only have one children called "ship".

EDIT: Forgot to mention. Each of these "ship"-s are supposed to be variables. They are declared like this:

```
Image ship = new Image();
```

As far as I know, I can only put these variables into the canvas.Children.Add(). But if I add the first ship, I cant add more.

EDIT2: I am a bloody moron. I should just use an array.

Is there a work around this, or a better and easier way to create my ships?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: You may add several elements to the `Children` property of the `Canvas`. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Depending on how many users are on the server, I would have to name each Children myself as far as I know. I also would like to use the same code I have already, and while naming 1 or two ship (like ship1, ship2) is an option, if there are 50 users it would get pretty tedious. @mm8

Comment: Give each element a unique name. Or don't name them at all?

Comment: Sorry I may have been too hard to understand, its not easy for me to explain this. I am creating an Image element, which is named ship. As far as I know I can only put the Image "variable", which I named ship, into the canvas.Children.Add() method. So there I am, with an Image, what is called ship, but I need sometimes more than 50 of these Images on the screen.

Comment: Your questions makes no sense since you can add several `Images` to the `Children` collection of the `Canvas`. Did you try? What happened?

Comment: As a note, `new Uri("C:/Users/Szabi/Desktop/spaceship.png", UriKind.Relative)` makes no sense. That path is obviously not relative.

Comment: Yes, you sohuld just use an array. Specifically, though, if each ship has an ID, try using a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2), where the key is the ID and the value is the image.